# Crystal Report direct saving as PDF, instead of viewing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to make a report from ASP.Net, in Crystal Report. I want, when user click on print, it should simply show a browser dialog of Save,Open,Save as, and PDF should be saved, or Crystal Report print preview should appear, I don't want to display report first in Viewer then click on button to get print or PDF, I want simply from clicking on asp button, I have all the idea of parameters and know how to make report, my question is just to not to show viewer and take report from asp button in a form of PDF or print preview dialog to print. I have used the Export method of .Net for Crystal Report, but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ExportCRtoPDF10062006161918PM/ExportCRtoPDF.aspx

Here is the quote from the site:

> The following steps will guide you to achieve the same:
>
> Add crystal report (.cr) file to your ASP.NET application.
>   Add a report instance on the page level.
>
> **Dim report As MyReport = New MyReport**
>
> Populate reports data on Page_Init
>
> **Dim ds As DataSet = GetData()**
>
> **report.SetDataSource(ds)**
>
> Export Report
>
> **report.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, False, "ExportedReport")**
>
> If you wish to format report to other formats, just change the ExportFormatType enumeration value to > your desired format.
>
> If you wish to download the report, then you simply change the third parameter of >ExportToHttpResponse method in Step 4 to True.

Answer (score 5):

You can generate a PDF by Using a Crystal Report and piece of code....

- First: Generate a Crystal Report as per your requirements.
- Second: Use the below code to generate the PDF:

  - Place the following name spaces at the top of the code page

    ```
    Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
    ```
  - Variable Declaration

    ```
    Dim CrReport As New CrystalReport1() // Report Name
    Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
    Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
    Dim CrFormatTypeOptions as New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
    ```
  - Set the destination path and file name

    ```
    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\RichText.pdf"
    ```
  - Specify a page range (optional)

    ```
    crFormatTypeOptions.FirstPageNumber = 1 // Start Page in the Report
    crFormatTypeOptions.LastPageNumber = 3 // End Page in the Report
    crFormatTypeOptions.UsePageRange = True
    ```
  - Set export options

    ```
    CrExportOptions = crReport.ExportOptions

    With CrExportOptions

    // Set the destination to a disk file
    .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile

    // Set the format to PDF
    .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat

    // Set the destination options to DiskFileDestinationOptions object
    .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
    .FormatOptions = crFormatTypeOptions

    End With
    ```
  - Trap any errors that occur on export

    ```
    Try
        // Export the report
        CrReport.Export()
    Catch err As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(err.ToString())
    End Try
    ```

Thats it.... Now you are ready to create a PDF of the Report.